# Stop raising of create event for Filewatcher control for automatic generated temporary file of Original content

Tags: c#, windows

I am using filewatcher control in my winform app. I am performing uploading task by handling its events. 
Now problem is that when I create any new document in directory(**which is watched under FileWatcher control**) uploading function starts and it uploads the document.(**Which I want**) but with creating new document in this directory system generates temporary file and it also uploaded to the server(**Which I don't want**).

As for example if I am creating a new word document named ***Microsoft Word Document.docx*** in **xyz** directory(**This directory is  watched under FileWatcher control**) then system create another file like **~$w Microsoft Word Document.docx** for that doc. and this both files are uploading to server. 

Here I have take an example for a word file. Uploading content may be any(**not fix**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got a solution. I use a little validation before adding file in Queue for upload.

```
FileAttributes attr = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(e.FullPath);

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);     

if ((attr & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden || fi.Extension == ".tmp")
{
     return;
}
```

If I am getting  file attribute hidden or its extension then I return from there.

Thats all :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just detect the temporary filename and ignore it? You may well find it has some attributes which make it obviously not-a-normal-file, or you could just spot the naming convention which Word uses. (How likely is it that you'll really want a file beginning with "$"?)

Comment: Thank Jon for guidance. Got a solution